# How do I find against which git commit a launchpad package was built?

Tags: git, ubuntu, bazaar, launchpad

There's a launchpad ppa, which is delivering new packages on a daily basis built from an imported git repository as its source.

I need to figure out for a given successful built ([example](https://launchpad.net/~snwh/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+builds?build_text=paper-icon-theme&build_state=built)) the corresponding git commit SHA-1 hash.
Is there any way to figure this out from within Launchpad's webpage itself?

Comment: Note that I can build my packages on Launchpad without first doing a `git commit` + `git push`. So it's not likely that would ever work...

Answer (score 0):

The only Git references seen in the logs of an artifactor listed in that launchpad ppa are not helpful.
For example: [buildlog_ubuntu-xenial-amd64.paper-icon-theme_1.5.716-201806100126~daily~ubuntu16.04.1_BUILDING.txt.gz](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/373939822/buildlog_ubuntu-xenial-amd64.paper-icon-theme_1.5.716-201806100126~daily~ubuntu16.04.1_BUILDING.txt.gz) includes:

```
Buildd toolchain package versions: 
   launchpad-buildd_161 ...
   git-build-recipe_0.3.4~git201611291343.dcee459~ubuntu16.04.1 
   git_1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.4 ...
...
Homepage: https://github.com/snwh/paper-icon-theme
```

None of that helps identifying the [right commit from `snwh/paper-icon-theme`](https://github.com/snwh/paper-icon-theme/commits/master).

So you need to rely on the deliverable itself, which might include the commit reference.
See for instance [`paper-icon-theme.spec`](https://github.com/snwh/paper-icon-theme/blob/3f01b6bcce57a4f7e92e4a5b411621af28bde95e/paper-icon-theme.spec#L16-L17) which has a line which should be replaced at build time:

```
# GitHub Stuff
%global commit0 40-CHARACTER-HASH-VALUE
```

As [commit af069ae](https://github.com/snwh/paper-icon-theme/commit/af069ae3617b2f24eea1d73d03fdf454131b7946) details:

> This is because files are named as `%{name}-%{commit0}.tar.gz` on download.

It refers to:

- [Installation Instructions](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/user501254/Paper/)
- an example of the [paper-icon-theme.spec once packaged](https://github.com/user501254/packaging/blob/master/paper/rpmbuild/SPECS/paper-icon-theme.spec#L16-L17)

Comment: I own the Copr repo that you mentioned above :-). Earlier when this project was a bazaar mirror of the GitHub project, finding the corresponding git commit was straightforward using this [request](https://github.com/user501254/packaging/blob/e1643443b1ce7bac94ff464d3a0d55565b925497/paper/copr.sh#L26). However the new git mirror on launchpad doesn't seem to offer any such functionality. I'm really not in favour of downloading any archives just to get a single commit hash.

Comment: @AsheshKumarSingh I believe the idea if commit af069ae is to suggests the name of the archive itself includes the commit SHA1, without needing to download it.